# Package glossaries print acronyms instead of description

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am writing an article for MDPI journal and I would like to use my list of glossaries instead of typing them by hand (which is what is done in the template).

I have tried the solution provided here: [List of Acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300925/list-of-acronyms) but nothing seems to work. I think that I am mixing glossary terms and acronyms and this is why it doesn't work, but I think this is a legitimate thing to do as a lot of glossary terms have acronyms.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{import}


\usepackage[nopostdot,style=super,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

% Tell glossaries package that glossaries start here
\makeglossaries
% Import the glossaries package
\subimport*{./}{glossary.tex}

\begin{document}


This is an acronym: \gls{dht}.\par

\section{This is how it should look like}

\noindent 
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
MDPI & Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute\\
DOAJ & Directory of open access journals\\
TLA & Three letter acronym\\
LD & linear dichroism
\end{tabular}

\section{This is how it looks like}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

and glossary.tex contains:

```
\newglossaryentry{dht}
{
    type=\acronymtype,
    name={DHT},
    first={Distributed Hash Table (DHT)},
    long={Distributed Hash Table},
    firstplural={Distributed Hash Tables (DHTs)},
    plural={DHTs},
    description={I want the long here, not the description}
}
```

I have two separate questions, one regarding style formatting and the other regarding what is shown in the abbreviations table. This SO question refers to the latter. I have also checked: [Combined glossary and list of acronyms: Same backlinks for full entry and acronym, or none at all at the latter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280887/combined-glossary-and-list-of-acronyms-same-backlinks-for-full-entry-and-acrony) but although I think it is related to my question, I can't come with a proper solution as I have not enough expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\newacronym` to define abbreviations with the `glossaries` package. The `glossary.tex` file should look like:

```
\newacronym{dht}{DHT}{Distributed Hash Table}
\newacronym{mdpi}{MDPI}{Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
\newacronym[longplural={Directories of open access journals}]
 {doaj}{DOAJ}{Directory of open access journals}
\newacronym{tla}{TLA}{Three letter acronym}
\newacronym{ld}{LD}{linear dichroism}
```

The document should input this file using just `\input` or `\loadglsentries`. Fancier inclusion commands, such as `\subimport` or `\include`, should be avoided.

The document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[nopostdot,style=super,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\input{glossary}% input definitions

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{dht}. Next use: \gls{dht}.

Reset.\glsreset{dht}

First use plural \glspl{dht}. Next use plural: \glspl{dht}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]
\end{document}
```

The document build process (assuming the file is called `myDoc.tex`):

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex MyDoc
```

Or (if you don't have Perl):

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries-lite myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Result:

[image: image of document]

If you want all defined entries included, even if they haven't been used in the document, add `\glsaddallunused` at the end of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[nopostdot,style=super,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\input{glossary}% input definitions

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{dht}. Next use: \gls{dht}.

Reset.\glsreset{dht}

First use plural \glspl{dht}. Next use plural: \glspl{dht}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]
\glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

The vertical gaps are caused by a change in letter group. Use `nogroupskip` to omit them:

```
\usepackage[nopostdot,style=super,nonumberlist,toc,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
```

If you want the entries listed in order of definition, use `sort=def`:

```
\usepackage[nopostdot,style=super,nonumberlist,toc,nogroupskip,sort=def]{glossaries}
```

If you want to use the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package, you need to replace `\setacronymstyle` with `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=super,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,sort=def]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\input{glossary}% input definitions

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{dht}. Next use: \gls{dht}.

Reset.\glsreset{dht}

First use plural \glspl{dht}. Next use plural: \glspl{dht}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]
\glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

In this case (all defined entries and in order of definition and `nonumberlist`) you can simplify the build process:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=super,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\input{glossary}% input definitions

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{dht}. Next use: \gls{dht}.

Reset.\glsreset{dht}

First use plural \glspl{dht}. Next use plural: \glspl{dht}.

\printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]
\end{document}
```

The build process is now just:

```
pdflatex myDoc
```

Result:

[image: image of document]

With `glossaries-extra`, you can change `\newacronym` to `\newabbreviation`, in which case you also need to change `\acronymtype` to `\glsxtrabbrvtype` and just use `\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}` (without the optional argument).

If you have a mixture of some abbreviations with descriptions and some without, the best method is to use `glossaries-extra`, which allows multiple abbreviation styles.

For example, use `\newacronym` for terms without a description:

```
\newacronym{dht}{DHT}{Distributed Hash Table}
```

with the `acronym` style set to `long-short`:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
```

and use `\newabbreviation` for terms with a description:

```
\newabbreviation[description={description text here}]{tla}{TLA}{Three letter acronym}
```

and use the `long-short-desc` style:

```
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-desc}
```

You might need a different glossary style or split the entries into two glossaries, depending on how they need to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the long response. What happens if I want acronyms to have a description? I mean, what happens if I also want to use them in a glossary?

Comment: @vicaba I've updated my answer. If they all have descriptions, then just change the style from `long-short` to `long-short-desc`, otherwise if you want a mixture you can use `glossaries-extra` as in the appended part of my answer. There are a lot of styles to choose from. You might want to have a look at [Abbreviation Styles](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/sample-abbr-styles.shtml)